# How can I navigate between pages in .NET MAUI without using Shell?

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI app and I'm not using Shell.

Using Shell I would do the following to navigate between pages.

```cs
App.ApplicationShell.PushAsync(new SomePage());
```

Now without using the Shell, how can I navigate between pages?

Here is my App class:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    //public static AppShell ApplicationShell;  <<< No shell

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //App.ApplicationShell = new AppShell();    << No shell
        //MainPage = ApplicationShell;
                
        this.MainPage = new SomePage();             
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage

Answer (score 5):

## Shell Navigation

> Using Shell I would do the following to navigate between pages.
>
> ```cs
> App.ApplicationShell.PushAsync(new SomePage());
> ```

That's **not** how you do Shell-based navigation. By calling `PushAsync()`, you're simply adding a page onto the [navigation stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage#push-pages-to-the-navigation-stack), *independent* of using *[Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation)* or a *[NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage)*.

MAUI's Shell actually uses URI-based navigation with routes:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//SomePage");
```

No navigation stack is created when navigating between routes that are part of the visual hierarchy of Shell, i.e. when they are defined as `<ShellContent>` elements in *AppShell.xaml*, for example:

```xml
<Shell
  x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views">

  <ShellContent
    Title="Home"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />

  <TabBar>
    <Tab Title="SomePage">
      <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SomePage}"
        Route="SomePage" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="OtherPage">
      <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:OtherPage}"
        Route="OtherPage" />
    </Tab>
  </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

## Navigation Stack

This code

```cs
await App.ApplicationShell.PushAsync(new SomePage());
```

is equivalent to

```cs
await Navigation.PushAsync(new SomePage());
```

Whenever you call `PushAsync()` *(on the `INavigation` object)*, you create a [navigation stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage#push-pages-to-the-navigation-stack) as long as `MainPage` is set to either a *Shell* or a *NavigationPage*.

Therefore, if you don't want to use *Shell*, you can still use the navigation stack based approach. All you need to do is use a *NavigationPage* as the root page, which you can do as follows:

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SomePage());
```

This initializes the `NavigationPage` with `SomePage` as the first page. You can then navigate from that to any other page (which is added on top) by calling

```cs
await Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
```

## Direct Navigation

Alternatively, you can also set the `MainPage` directly to a different `Page` object, in which case you won't have a navigation stack and thus cannot navigate back and forth between open pages:

```cs
// set SomePage
App.MainPage = new SomePage();

// "go" to OtherPage by replacing SomePage
App.MainPage = new OtherPage();
```

This latter approach is only useful when you have different stages in your app, such as displaying a loading or login page before the actual app content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `command` to control the navigation.

First, Writing the `command` code in the xaml file.

```
 <TextCell Text="this is a text"
                          Detail="Select text on focus"
                          Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{x:Type views:NextPage}" />
```

You can put the `Command and CommandParameter` in the element. CommandParameter contains the page name which you want to go.

Second, you can create a `ICommand` named NavigateCommand to bind the Command in xaml and write a method to control the Command.

```
public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>(
            async (Type pageType) =>
            {
                Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            });

        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

NavigateCommand will pass the data to this method and change the type to `Page` then you can use the `await Navigation.PushAsync(page);` method to navigate the page.

Comment: I've added -1 because the question was about not using the shell. From the code snippet, it looks like, he is looking for an answer without using the NavigationPage. I lend on this question because I'm looking for an answer to a similar problem.

Comment: @SebastianBusek That's simply wrong. Navigation in MAUI without Shell means only using a navigation stack, for which you need a NavigationPage (preferred), or always setting the `App.MainPage` object to a different page instance (discouraged). Shell and NavigationPage both use `PushAsync()` to add a new page on top of another, because that's how a navigation stack is used in MAUI.

Comment: @Julian, no, simply wrong is the framework/technology. I mean, not able to use/write custom navigation layer is simply no-go for serious development. Sure, for 90% (boring) applications it's fine, I guess, however I don't like working on boring things. Of course, I tried assigning MainPage directly, however it didn't work, because some dependency required by framework is not set (worked it Xamarin, however). That's being said, but I am no longer using MAUI for development.